# Third party IIS Module not printing to log files

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, webdav, iis-10

I have an asp.net core application hosted and webdav enabled in IIS for storing files as well. I want to know when a user saves a file in the webdav server (ie, if opened and saved in Microsoft word). I have put together this IIS module to try and intercept all http requests so I can find out what a webdav HTTP requests look like and then hopefully create a if statement using this logic once I can identify the save request. So far here is the IIS module I have created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace WebDAVTargetDetectorIIS
{
    public class LoggingModule : IHttpModule
    {
        #region IHttpModule Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(OnPreRequestHandlerExecute);
            context.PostLogRequest += new EventHandler(PostLogEvent);
        }

        #endregion

        public void OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
            HttpRequest request = app.Context.Request;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]))
            {
                request.ServerVariables.Set("REMOTE_ADDR", request["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]);
            }
        }

        public void PostLogEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
            HttpRequest request = app.Context.Request;
            app.Response.AppendToLog("This is a test");

        }
    }
}
```

I have created the BIN folder in the root folder of my web application and used the IIS Manager to add the new module. It is added to the end of the ordered list. The log files in IIS seem to save to "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1" however my module does not seem to be printing my test line in there. Is there a particular reason the code above would not implement on any even a login request? Or should I be attaching this to some other event?

Comment: The tutorial talks about three options, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-a-module-using-net#deploy-to-application and each should be used under conditions (which beginners can often get confused). So if you are not familiar with the related parts, find a good book on IIS extensibility or hire someone with more experience. There are samples like https://github.com/cloudflare/ModCloudFlareIIS as well.

Comment: Your example from github was super helpful so thank you! I have updated my code above to the example in github but following their instructions allowed for me to get the module installed in IIS manager! My issue is even using their simplified code as an example I am not able to print to the log files of the server similar to what they do. Any reason you can think of?